# Java JFrame rectangle in window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

so i'm trying to put Rectangle2D.Float in window using JFrame but when i'm compiling code i'm getting just blank window without rectangle. Can you guys take look on it and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
package zestaw8;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class Plansza85 extends JPanel
{
   Shape figura;
   Plansza85(Shape figura)            
   {                                
      this.figura=figura;
   }                                
}

public class Zestaw8_cw85 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)                
   {                                                     
      Shape obj1;                                        
      obj1=new Rectangle2D.Float(100,100,140,140);      

      zestaw8.Plansza85 p;                                         
      p=new zestaw8.Plansza85(obj1);

      JFrame jf=new JFrame();                            
      jf.setTitle("Plansza p");                       
      jf.setSize(400,400);                               
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
      jf.setVisible(true);
      jf.add(p);
   }
}
```

Comment: Swap the last two commands, putting `setVisible()` last.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).  `Rectangle2D` is a graphics primitive, which needs to be painted through the normal painting custom painting process

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how painting works in Swing.

Start by looking at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).  `Rectangle2D` is a graphics primitive, which needs to be painted through the normal custom painting process

As per the common recommendations of [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) you should override the `paintComponent` method of the `Plansza85` and paint the `Shape` through the `Graphics2D` API, something like...

[image: Painted]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Shape obj1;
                obj1 = new Rectangle2D.Float(100, 100, 140, 140);

                Plansza85 p;
                p = new Plansza85(obj1);

                JFrame jf = new JFrame();
                jf.setTitle("Plansza p");
                jf.add(p);
                jf.pack();
                jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jf.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class Plansza85 extends JPanel {

        Shape figura;

        Plansza85(Shape figura) {
            this.figura = figura;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (figura == null) {
                return super.getPreferredSize();
            }
            Rectangle2D bounds = figura.getBounds2D();
            double width = bounds.getMaxX();
            double height = bounds.getMaxY();

            return new Dimension((int)width + 1, (int)height + 1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getForeground());
            g2d.draw(figura);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

for example.

I've also overridden the `getPreferredSize` method to generate an appropriate sizing hint for the component based on the size of the shape, I've done this because I dislike guess work and the window also includes variable sized borders and title bars which will change the size the panel if you only rely on `setSize`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `paintComponent` method of `Plansza85`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class Plansza85 extends JPanel {
    private Shape figura;

    Plansza85(Shape figura) {
        this.figura = figura;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(figura);
    }
}

public class Zestaw8_cw85 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape obj1;
        obj1 = new Rectangle2D.Float(100, 100, 140, 140);

        Plansza85 p;
        p = new Plansza85(obj1);

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Plansza p");
        jf.setSize(400, 400);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(p);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: this `Rectangle bounds = this.figura.getBounds();
        g.drawRect((int) bounds.getX(), (int) bounds.getY(), (int) bounds.getWidth(), (int) bounds.getHeight());` would be better replaced with `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; g2.draw(figura);`. Not only is it shorter, but if the spec is changed in future to include ellipses or polygons, it will work as expected!

Comment: An edit to the answer would be more productive than agreeing that I'm correct. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I’ll do that, I’m using the stackoverflow mobile app.  Give a hour :-)